# Toggle decrease button to delete button when value = 1

Tags: javascript, php, html, button, toggle

I have this quantity input that is controlled by increase decrease buttons.
The decrease button should change to delete button when its value = 1 else it should stay on minus button, so I can modify quantity in one column without an extra delete column. Can anyone pls help me.

[image]

```
<form action="cart.php" method="post" >


    <div class="input-group-prepend" >
    <button style="width:45px" 
            type="submit" 
            type="button" 
            class="btn-add btn btn-primary" 
            onclick="plusbot(' . $key_of_session . '), submit()">
    <i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
    </div>


    <input id="kilohere_' . $key_of_session . '" 
           class="form-control counter" 
           onchange="this.form.submit()"   
           data-min="1" 
           max="99" 
           name="quantity" 
           type="text" value="' . $each_item['quantity'] . '" 
           size="1" 
           maxlength="2"/>
        
    
    <div class="input-group-append">
    <button style="width:45px" 
            type="submit" onclick="minusbot(' . $key_of_session . '), submit()"  class="btn-subtract btn btn-primary">
    <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
    </button>
    </div>


    <input name="item_to_adjust" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="' . $item_id . '" />
    <input name="size" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="' . $size . '" />
    <input name="key_of_session" 
           type="hidden" 
           value="' . $key_of_session . '">
    </form>
```

// The delete Button:
[image]

```
    <button type="submit" 
                class="btn btn-primary" 
                name="deleteBtn' . $item_id . '" 
                id="button">
        <i class="fas fa-trash-alt"></i>
    </button>
        <input name="index_to_remove" 
               type="hidden" 
               value="' . $i . '" />
```

// The Javascript:

```
<script>
    function minusbot(id)
    {
        let inputField = document.getElementById('kilohere_' + id)
        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) - 1;
        var checknumifzero = parseInt(inputField.value);

        if(checknumifzero < 1) //preventing to get negative value
        {
            inputField.value = 1;
        }
    }   

    function plusbot(id)
    {
        let inputField = document.getElementById('kilohere_' + id)
        inputField.value = parseInt(inputField.value) + 1;
        var checknumiffifty = parseInt(inputField.value);

        if(checknumiffifty > 50) //just a limit
        {
            inputField.value = 50;
        }
    }

</script>
```

Comment: The form is always getting submitted, right? So you can add a php if else condition

Comment: Can you give an example pls? Can't imagine with php because its an output alread I tryed to add a switch case for quantity but could not figure out to get the condition in cartoutput.

Comment: I send you email, once all of your doubts cleared let me know